# SQL multiple betweens joined by or

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a hierarchy stored as a nested set in a mySQL database, and want to find all the parents of a node, which I can do like this:

```
SELECT id FROM nested_set WHERE 837461 BETWEEN lft AND rgt;
```

But I want to do this for a potentially large number of nodes, say 10,000. I can do this by chaining a set of BETWEENs together, e.g.

```
SELECT id FROM nested_set WHERE 
    44102 BETWEEN lft AND rgt OR
    837461 BETWEEN lft AND rgt OR
    164462 BETWEEN lft AND rgt OR
    566562 BETWEEN lft AND rgt OR
    768916 BETWEEN lft AND rgt OR 
    ...
```

But this seems very tedious and I guess could exceed the SQL statement size. Is there any more efficient way to do this, rather than creating a query with 10,000 chained OR statements?

Comment: Under what circumstances would a selected node *not* appear in the result ?

Comment: This hierarchy is a bifurcating one (actually, a biological "tree of life" at www.onezoom.org). The query select the parents of a set of tips in the heirarchy. For instance, all the animals are between lft=759126 and rgt=2123179. If the query includes only "animal" numbers, then no plants (left=117464, rgt=507078) will be returned. But there will also be a good number of "sister groups" within animals not returned - e.g. if there are no apes in the query (lft=837457, rgt=837467) then none of these nodes (not just the tips, but the slightly higher level clusters) will be returned.

Comment: Hmm, unless there's a pattern behind that literals, that I don't see and that allows them to be somehow generated, I suppose you have to write all that literals down one way or another. What could be an option is to insert the constants in a (temporary) table and then have a more generic query working on the set in that table (maybe with a join or `EXISTS`). But still you had to write the all the literals in the `INSERT` statement(s).

Comment: Do you have to use SQL for this? I think this would be better solved using a graph database like Neo4j.

Comment: Thanks @stickybit . I guess I would have to write down all the literals, but they are all using the same `lft` and `rgt` columns, so it strikes me that there might be a terser (and possibly more efficient) way of expressing it in SQL.

Comment: @Dai - all the data is already in mySQL and it's pretty efficient for what I need. I'm not sure that a tree traversal will be much quicker, as lots of the higher level nodes are shared between each selected tip.

Comment: You can insert all the literal values into a temporary table T(id), and join back to the nested set table (ns) with the predicate T.id BETWEEN ns.lft and ns.rgt.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this qualifies as an improvement or even solution to you, but I'll give it a shot: As I already commented you could use a temporary table storing the nodes.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE nodes
                       (node integer,
                        INDEX (node));

INSERT INTO nodes
            (node)
            VALUES (44102),
                   (837461),
                   (164462),
                   (566562),
                   ...;
```

You could then use it to do your `SELECT` with an inner join.

```
SELECT ns.id
       FROM nested_set ns
            INNER JOIN nodes n
                       ON n.node BETWEEN ns.lft
                                         AND ns.rgt);
```

Note that you may need to use `DISTINCT` if the nodes aren't unique or more than one given node is in one and the same range.

An alternative uses `EXISTS`.

```
SELECT ns.id
       FROM nested_set ns
       WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                            FROM nodes n
                            WHERE n.node BETWEEN ns.lft
                                                 AND ns.rgt);
```

The index on the temporary table may be supporting performance. For the table `nested_set` I'd try indexes on `(lft, rgt, id)`, `(lft, rgt)` or at least `(lft)`.

Of course you could also use a derived table of `UNION ALL`s like

```
...    
(SELECT 44102 node
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 837461 node
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 164462
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 566562
 ...) nodes
...
```

to join or select existence from. But then there'd be no supporting index as in the temporary table. With smaller sets however that index may not have so much weight anyways.